# How can I set a file to be "in use"

Tags: windows-xp

I need to fabricate a "file in use" scenario. I am programming exception handling for this particular scenario but I am unable to come up with a way to put a file "in use" so other programs are unable to delete or modify it.

Is there a simple way to do this that I'm overlooking?

Comment: i get this on windows 10

Comment: i usually just open up a dsaved ocument then create new worksheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to open that file with `Excel` application. I do not remember what actions exactly it disallows, but deletion for sure.

Comment: Excel also seems to be particularly aggressive about not allowing other applications to access files it has open.

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Then write couple of lines of C/C#/VB code :)

Comment: Actually Excel does the trick!

Comment: @dsolimano repost your advice as answer please

Comment: @dsolimano, if you post an answer I'll mark yours as the solution

Comment: As far as I can tell Excel behavior on locking files changes according Excel version. Not every version behaves the same.

Answer (score 1):

Write another program that opens a text file, writes some text to it but does not close the file. That should make sure that it is in use.